# Circuit to detect amperage?

Tags: current-measurement, amperage

Is there a circuit which can detect how much amps are flowing through it, and if the amperage falls below a certain level to output some signal?  (e.g. to direct the voltage to a different output)

Due to getting only vague answers on the question [How to attain a topping charge for a lead-acid battery?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/176642/how-to-attain-a-topping-charge-for-a-lead-acid-battery), I decided to rephrase what I need in a different manner.  I am very new at these things, so I apologize in advance if there is some way I am not explaining myself well; or maybe this is completely trivial to look up somewhere, and that's the reason I have not gotten any answers other than those of the type "Yes, this can be done".

Comment: [Sure you will find what you are looking for here.](https://www.google.dk/search?q=current%20sung&safe=off&biw=1491&bih=858&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=DO-KVemGHIHQsgHwroDQCw&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#safe=off&tbm=isch&q=current%20detector%20circuit) Because I could not comment yet, and this will not disappear, never.

Comment: After doing the search, the following page describes what I need: [A Current Sensing Tutorial--Part 1: Fundamentals, EETimes 2012](http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1279404)

Comment: Try [this](http://www.planetanalog.com/document.asp?doc_id=527795) or [this](http://www.deeptronic.com/high-side-current-sensing-using-transistor-for-current-limiting-control/).

Comment: @JustMe, I stumbled here and tried to see your links. The second link results in 404 error (discontinued/dead link). The first one doesn’t load images, just text. Searching for “high side and low side current sensing” I found this link, but still very conceptual only. http://www.worldofindie.co.uk/?p=216. In case you have similar references to what you meant, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Here is a circuit that should do what you want.   It uses the [LT6100](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/6100fd.pdf) is that it has variable gain and 0.5% accuracy.  I have used this chip in a commercial product.

[image]

If you use it with a 100 mΩ resistor, a 1A load with drop 100 mV across the resistor. Using a gain of 20, this will give a 2v output. By adjusting the voltage divider feeding the + lead of the comparator, you can set the threshold you need.

If you combine the LT6100 with a 100 mΩ 0.5% resistor, you will have 1% accuracy for the combination.

The LT6100 is available [from Digi-Key](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/LT6100CMS8%23PBF/LT6100CMS8%23PBF-ND/1620561) for $2.36.