# Lead acid battery: What happens if very low charging current is applied for an extended period?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, charger, lead-acid, battery-chemistry

What would happen to a 40 Ah lead acid battery if the charging current is as low as 750 mA?

Would it get charged to its full capacity, say from 12 V to 12.7 V after a long duration or go permanently bad in the process?

Comment: Please edit your question to distinguish clearly between battery capacity (Ah, mAh) and current (A, mA).  You are mixing them up.

Comment: At 750mA, a 40 Ah battery would get charged in a couple days.  If you continue to pump 750mA into it indefinitely, you will overcharge it, and that causes the electrolyte to start boiling (very bad).   This releases explosive & corrosive hydrogen gas (depending on the type of lead acid battery involved).  Whether or not gas is actually released, damage to the battery WILL occur.   What you want to do is, after your cell hits the target voltage, you apply a "float" voltage, just a trickle of current.

Comment: Thankyou kyle you did solve my doubt thankyou very much

Answer (score 4):

For a 40 Ah lead acid battery, 750 mA exceeds the self-discharge rate. The 750 mA current will cause the voltage to rise. If you allow the voltage to climb above the recommended float voltage for the type of battery, the battery will be degraded or destroyed. The damage will be progressive. Doing it for 1 day may not cause much damage. But I am pretty sure that forcing 750 mA into a 40 Ah lead battery for 6 months will lead to total destruction of the battery. Most lead batteries will be OK at 14.5 V for a few hours (but make sure you read-up for more information on your specific battery type).

If you limit the voltage to, let's say, 13.6 V, then the battery may last a long time. Like several years.

This is just a quick answer. Lead acid batteries are actually the most complicated of all the common rechargeable battery types. They have lots of little quirks you have to pay attention to if you want to get the best possible life out of them. However, they do reasonably well in float service and are much cheaper than any lithium or nickel chemistry battery.

Comment: Thankyou mkeith for your amazing response thankyou

Answer (score 1):

It's fine, its called trickle charging and it actually is better for the battery than charging at the max rate. I've done this before with a regular lab bench supply that didn't have enough current output and left it overnight.

Whatever supply you use, the max voltage of the battery should not be exceeded. Just set the supply to to the max charging voltage for your battery chemistry. If you can set a current limit (to 750mA) and measure the battery voltage (to make sure its good and not shorted) and then you can let it sit.

There is a much better article [here](https://www.powerstream.com/SLA.htm)

Comment: Thankyou geek you have helped me a lot my sincere thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please observe that **your only charging parameter** is the (constant) **current set at 750mA**. The answers will initially consider just that, then elaborate other situations.

### Question 1:

> What would happen to a 40 Ah lead acid battery if the charging current is as low as 750 mA?

**Charging capability = Yes**
The LA battery will be charged at C/50 current rate: 0.75/40 ~ 1/50.
If battery if fully discharged, it will reach full charge after 50 hours (2 full days).
However, if the battery is just partially discharged, it will reach the “full-charged” state much sooner.

### Question 2:

> Would it get charged to its full capacity, say from 12 V to 12.7 V after a long duration?
> or
> Would it go permanently bad in the process?

**Overcharging risk damages = a Real possibility**
Surely yes for the first part (100% charged) and likely yes for the second part (risk of permanent damage).
After battery is 100% charged, it reaches a voltage level that it is not able to store energy.
Then, the current injected into the LA battery is used to electrolyze the water in the solution, generating hydrogen and oxygen gases - known as **gassing**, and depleting the electrolyte level. Continuing this, the Lead plates are exposed to air and if left uncovered they will be *permanently damaged*.

### Implicit Question: How to avoid damages?

The Current limited phase is just the first phase of a LA battery charging process, where about 80% of complete charge is processed chemically in the battery. This phase is sometimes called bulk charging stage - see [this Chargetek page](https://chargetek.com/basic-information.html) (and this edited graph):

[image]

When battery reaches a given voltage level, the charger needs to stop injecting current and the *chargers control now becomes a constant voltage* set at a Floating Voltage level.
This level is dependent of the ambient (battery) temperature, but for indoor temperatures V_float ~= 13.5V.
Above V_float, gassing can occur, and a 2-stage charger is (or should be) designed to avoid gassing.

**A 2-stage charger performs these 2 phases**:

- Bulk-charging at current-limited (or constant current) phase.
- Maintainer of charge, at constant voltage phase.

As can be seen, such Charger is basically a power supply, where

- V_set = V_float  and
- I_set = I_bulk.

There are several charging algorithms with advantages compared to the simple 2-stage charger above.

**3-stage charger**:
A very effective and popular method is the 3-stage charging, which allows a faster charging with some cell equalization.
I discussed in detail this kind of  [charger here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/605293), their charging parameters (voltage, current, time, etc.) and proposed a few linear circuit variants.